# I want to add content from my website to the html permanently

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to build a website in which users can add information, like craigslist. I want the website user to be able to click a button fill out a form and add another box. For instance, if there is a three by three grid and the user clicks on the add button, I want a form to appear, them to fill it out and one more box to be permanently added to the grid. Of course I could make it happen with Javascript and JQuery but it isn't permanent. Thanks:)

Comment: This is a very broad question. All I can say is that you should look into databases. You might also be able to do something with HTML5 local storage but then only the user in question would be able to see the changes they made.

Comment: Learn about a server side language. PHP, Node, JAva, .NET, Rails, Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Implement this using server side languages like PHP /Node JS, ASP.net, Java, Ruby or you can use Local Storage of the browser (this gives limited storage capacity ). read this for more details. [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: I guess what I really want to know is how to amend an html file using php.

Comment: @Daniel you can follow up simple tutorial set to learn about this. 
[1] http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_intro.asp
[2] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=114ddqVNNws
Happy Learning :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already know PHP, you will need to learn it for this.  Also, you will need to make sure that you understand how to validate input because letting users add to your database can be a very dangerous thing to do if you don't understand how things like script injection works.